# Cocos2dx, How to detect touch on a part of a sprite?

Tags: touch, sprite, cocos2d-x-3.x

I want to seperately detect touch on a part of the sprite. For example if the sprite is a character consisting of face, arms, legs and other body parts. To be precise, these body parts are not separate sprites. Is there any way I can detect which part of the body is touched?

Answer (score 0):

you could use images that are totally transparent to create buttons over your body sprite. You set the dimension and position of your button to cover the desired body part and attach the button, with an action, to your body sprite. Of course, this will be a rectangular area and not the exact outline of the body part.